# sorting in mysql if multiple rows matches

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a doubt. how

`ORDER BY time_stamp ASC`

will work if 3 different rows have same time_stamp value??

okay I will paste my entire query

`SELECT
    mail
FROM
    table2
INNER JOIN
    table1 ON table2.wid = table1.id
WHERE
    table1.time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
AND
    table1.status<>200
GROUP BY
    table1.Id
ORDER BY
    table1.time_stamp ASC
LIMIT 2`

please anybody help me with an answer..

Comment: Is it a trick? To start a question from it's end and go to it's start? In any case, it's unclear what you're asking. Provide table structure, date and desired result sample.

Answer (score 0):

If three rows have the same timestamp value, then they will appear as three rows after the `order by`.  In arbitrary order.  If you want a *stable* sort (that is, one that always returns the same values), then include an `id` in the `order by` clause.

Your `group by` should ensure that you get different ids in the two rows coming from the query.

EDIT:

If you need all records matching 1 or two timestamps, do something like this:

```
select table1.email
from table1 join
     (SELECT time_stamp
      FROM table2 INNER JOIN
           table1
           ON table2.wid = table1.id
      WHERE table1.time_stamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND table1.status<>200
      ORDER BY table1.time_stamp ASC
      LIMIT 2
     ) limits
     on table1.time_stamp = limits.time_stamp
GROUP BY table1.Id;
```

This gets all `table1` records that match the timestamp.  You might have to repeat some of the `where` conditions.

Comment: @user007 . . . No, the `group by` ensures you get different ids.

Comment: the table names are misplaced.. i think u did that accidentally? ryt? any ways i tried with proper table names but unfortunately it didn't work..